# And/But with the use of several adjectives

Tags: sentence-choice

In the process of writing a letter, I have always had trouble in choosing between "and" and "but" when dealing with adjectives describing a person or a situation.

Let me use an example to illustrate where I lack understanding: which of the following sentences would be the most appropriate?

- "This person is smart, confident *but* also humble. Therefore she should be able to... etc"
- "This person is smart, confident *and* also humble. Therefore etc..."

All the adjectives used here aim to have a **meliorative** function. However "humble" aims to balance the "smart" and "confidence", therefore I would like to use "but" to accentuate this aim to counterweight.
Nevertheless my English teachers have told me that "but" only provides a strict contradiction which is not what I aim.

I would be grateful for new opinions in order to shed light on this topic. Thank you very much!

Comment: You over-complicate things by introducing the notion of "[a]meliorative function" ("weakening / softening" an assertion). Your teachers over-simplify by saying ***but*** "only provides a **strict contradiction**". The reality is that ***but*** introduces some kind of ***contrast*** (not necessarily a complete contradiction). And in your example it makes little sense to suppose ***humble*** is being contrasted with *both* the antecedents, since there IS no generally-understood contrast between ***humble*** and ***smart***. Only ***confident but humble*** makes a meaningful contrast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to contrast the person's humility with their intelligence/confidence, then **but** is the better choice.

If you want to add a characteristic rather than contrast, prefer **and**.

In your examples, **but** is the better fit as you are implying a contrast.

However you require the conjunction **and** between the words **smart** and **confident** in your first example:

> This person is smart **and** confident but also humble

You can see the reason for this if you break the sentence down: This person is smart **and** confident. **But** this person is also humble.

**But** is definitely NOT used ONLY to indicate a contradiction. Your teachers have misled you. It is mainly used to contrast thoughts or situations rather than contradict.

> I would like to buy the new Ford **but** I am also attracted by the latest Opel.
>   She would like to go for a walk **but** it looks like rain.